# polymorphic relation backwards query laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, polymorphism, table-relationships

I've been searching the web for the answer and haven't found any, so here's the problem:

I have 3 table:

Events
Tournaments
Leagues

Event table:
id
eventable_id
eventable_type (League or Tournament)

Tournaments table:
id
name

Leagues table:
id
name

What I want to do is get the event that has the name = Event name.

I tried:

```
$event = Events::get()->eventable->where('name', '=', $event_name)->first();
```

Without any success. I tried:

$event = Events::eventable()->where('name', '=', $event_name)->first();

No success and I have tried a lot of different ways and I just can't figure it out....

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) fetching one row is done like this:

```
$event = DB::table('events')->where('name', $event_name)->first();
```

Comment: I was hoping to have a simpler way... as it's the whole point of relationships... I guess no other way than using joins...

Comment: I think you are confusing relationships with ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Event is a reserved word in laravel. You may want to rename your model to something else.

OR... you could fiddle with the aliases array in app/config/app.php